# Nginx - Can't reach phpmyadmin with Laravel site

Tags: laravel, nginx

In my /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com file, I have the following settings, but I can't find example.com/phpmyadmin. However, the Laravel app on example.com/ is accessible and working fine. Phpmyadmin is installed in /usr/share/phpmyadmin and a symbolic link for it is created in /var/www/html/.

What am I missing here?

```
server {
         listen 80;
         listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

         # Webroot Directory for Laravel project
         root /var/www/example.com/public;
         index index.php index.html index.htm;

         # Your Domain Name
         server_name example.com;

         location / {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
         }

         location /phpmyadmin {
            root /var/www/html;
            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    root /var/www/html;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }
            location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                    root /var/www/html;
            }
        }


         # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
         location ~ \.php$ {
                 try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;
         }
 }
```

Comment: root for ur phpmyadmin is it correct ??
/var/www/html 
or
/var/www/html/phpmyadmin

Comment: Yes in /var/www/html, I have a symbolic link phpmyadmin which points to /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Comment: okay whats the error you getting?

Comment: Can you try this root inside 
location /phpmyadmin {
            root /var/www/html/phpmyadmin;

Comment: The browser doesn't find example.com/phpmyadmin and returns 404 not found

Comment: I don't think that will help since root is /var/www/html
and link is /phpmyadmin 
in nginx file

Comment: Use the `^~` modifier to prevent `.php` files from being processed by the wrong `location` block. Try: `location ^~ /phpmyadmin { ... }`